# How to create progress notification like android download manager service notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create notification like android download manager service notification(play store use it) that show two content text, progress in left and other text in right?(Bellow image). How can i do it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with bellow method:

```
 builder.setContentInfo("My info");
```

Text "My info" showed in left(or right) side of content text.

Comment: it's not working for me, is there something i'm missing?